# Matching %ff in Nginx rewrite rules

Tags: nginx, regex

I have some dubious requests coming into my server that contain `%ff` and `%FF` (e.g., `/blog/%ffupdates/`. I'm getting thousands of these daily and would like to start redirecting them to a 403. I currently have an endpoint that I use to blackhole things like this and would like to rewrite these URLs to point to that endpoint.

Currently, I am trying:

`rewrite ^/.*?%ff.*?$ https://domain.com/forbidden permanent;`

I fully understand that this might be too greedy of a match; however, I am just trying to get something to work initially.

Now, when I try this and view the debug log, it seems as though `%ff` is getting converted to `�` (yes, that's supposed to be the question mark diamond thingy).

For instance, there are things like this in the log:

`*4 "^/.*?%ff.*?$" does not match "/blog/�updates/"`

It seems that because `%ff` is converted, I cannot actually match the string.

I'm running Nginx 1.7.1 with SSL and SPDY.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to match this by regex. For instance:

```
location ~ /\xff/ {
    return 403;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! The exact regex did not work, but using `\xff` instead of `\%ff` worked well! Thanks!